# Android Database

Tags: android, database

I'm Working on android, so I want to know where the database will be stored? how to check it  stored or not?

Comment: what database are you taking about ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your applications database will be stored in `/data/data/<your package name>/databases`.

The method I usually use to check it would be to use the `sqlite3` command through the adb shell.  You can use the `.dump` command or `.schema` to view your databases current state.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use the DDMS perspective of Eclipse and look under `data/data/<your app package name>/databases`

Answer (score 1):

If you mean SQLiteDatabase on Android device, then:

/data/data/com.example.xxx/databases/xxx.db

Answer (score 0):

```
/data/data/<package_name>/databases/.
```

cf : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite
and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db